# MVC - Pass entire model as parameter to Url.Action in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I pass the entire model as a parameter to Url.Action orsimilar?

Actually, I pass a parameter to the controller and I load the model, but I would like to pass entire model.

```
window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Search", "Search", new { idSong = Model.IDSong })');
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To send object by using ajax without jquery

Answer (score 15):

Can you. Yes.

You can pass a simple model containing only properties which are values types or `string` using the overload that accepts `object` as the 3rd parameter

```
@Url.Action("Search", "Search", Model)
```

Would you want to? No.

Internally the method will create a `Dictionary` based on each properties name and `.ToString()` value and convert that to a query string. Not only will the resulting url be ugly, if you have a lot of properties, or the values of the properties contain long strings, you could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. But the main issue is that any properties which are complex objects or collections will cause binding to fail because, for example, a property which is `List<string>` will generate `..?somePropertyName=System.Collections.Generic.List[string]&....`

Pass just the model's `ID` as your doing now, and get the model again from the repository in your controller.

Comment: if we have other parameters like an int and another string and third model does creating anonymous object will work?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, Not sure if I have understood your comment, but if you mean can you do `@Url.Action("Search", "Search", new { id = 1, Model })` to post back another value that is not part of the model, then no you cant (`Model` becomes an nested object and method does not recursively generate query strings for complex objects - the result would be `../Search? id=1&Model=someAssembly.someClassName`)

Comment: so what is the recommended way in that case, if we have this kind of scenario

Comment: @EhsanSajjad The only (built in) choice AFAIK, is to create an anonymous object for each property of the model - `new { id = 1, firstName = Model.FirstName, lastName = Model.LastName , .... }` (I once created my own `Html.RouteValuesFor()` method that built a `RouteValueDictionary` based on model and did recursion, and also had an optional parameter for an anonymous object that would add extra values, but I never found a use for it)

Comment: your method approach looks good, but setting every property is a pain doing every time, can you share the snippet for the extension you wrote?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, Sure. Will get it from work tomorrow and ping you with a link.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, I have added the code in chat (link above)

Comment: can you share it here

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing a ViewBag instead:

```
Url.Action("Search", "Song", new { songId = ViewBag.SongId, songName = ViewBag.SongName})
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Search(string songId, string songName)
{
}
```