# How can i send search query to PagedListPager Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I want send search query in page 2 as in page1 in PageListMvc how can i do that?
I set my query to a class name SearchItems:

```
public class SearchItems
{
    public string[] productType{get;set;}
    public string[] manufactureName { get; set; }
    public string PriceRange { get; set; }
    public string[] Capacities { get; set; }
    public int[] Colors { get; set; }
}
```

This my Controller:

In my `ActionResult` some parameter are array string. User may select more types of items to search.

```
public ActionResult SearchResultByPage(int? page, string[] productType, string[] manufactureName, string PriceRange, string[] Capacities, int[] Colors,SearchItems currentFilter)
{
    SearchItems se = new SearchItems()
    {
        productType = productType,
        Capacities = Capacities,
        manufactureName = manufactureName,
        Colors = Colors,
        PriceRange = PriceRange
    };
    ViewBag.currentFilter = se;
    ...
}
```

and View:
`PageListPager` sent query as ajax with to parameter `page` and `currentFilter` that initialize with `ViewBag.currentFilter`.

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("SearchResultByPage", "Home", new{ page, currentFilter=ViewBag.currentFilter }),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "productsContent" }))
```

The result url is as follows:

`http://localhost:22877/Home/SearchResultByPage?page=3&currentFilter=KharidHafezeh.Data.ViewModels.SearchItems`

Comment: You cannot send a complex object containing collections to a GET method

Comment: For some more info, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219354/mvc-pass-entire-model-as-parameter-to-url-action-in-javascript/35220469?noredirect=1#comment66839140_35220469)