# send value from bootstrap table to method using data-url (value always null)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-table

I have a View contains a PartialView. This partial view contains a bootstrap table, To display the data inbootstrap table I use:
 `data-url=@Url.Action("getUsers", "User",new {user = ViewBag.User})` with "user" in parameter, but the problem "user" is always null. help plz

View:

- in Controller

  public Index()
  {
     return View();
  }

  - in HTML

  ```
      @Html.Action("ShowUsers", "User", new { user = Model }))

  </div>
  ```

PartialView(Bootstrap Table) ShowUsers:
 - in Controller

```
public ActionResult ShowUsers(Users user)
    {

        return PartialView(user);
    }
```

- in HTML @model Model.Users

  ```
      <table id="eventsTable"
             data-toggle="table"
             data-height="600"
             data-url=@Url.Action("GetUsers", "User",new {user = Model})
             data-pagination="true"
             data-search="true"
             data-show-refresh="true"
             data-show-toggle="true"
             data-show-columns="true"
             data-side-pagination="server"
             data-pagination-next-text="›"
             data-pagination-pre-text="‹"
             data-toolbar="#toolbar">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th data-field="Name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                  <th data-field="Email" data-sortable="true">Email</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
      </table>
  ```

And the method "GetUsers" for get users using Json:

```
public ActionResult GetUser(Users user) => it's always null, why ??
{
   ......
}
```

Comment: `Model.Users` is a complex object and you cannot pass a complex object using `Url.Action()` - look at the html it generates. If `Users` contains only simple properties, then using `data-url=@Url.Action("GetUsers", "User", Model)` may work

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219354/mvc-pass-entire-model-as-parameter-to-url-action-in-javascript/35220469#35220469) for more detail